# Задача "Пираты и монеты"

Tags: c

Пытался решить простенькую задачку на (решал на Си) на е-олипе, [вот сама задачка](http://www.e-olimp.com/problems/75)

> n пиратам удалось справедливо разделить клад из m золотых монет - каждый получил свою часть согласно своему пиратскому рангу и стажу. Самый молодой пират взял a монет, а каждый следующий пират брал на одну монету больше, чем предыдущий его коллега. Последним был капитан, которому досталось вдвое больше от запланированного, очевидно, что после него монет больше не осталось.
>
> Сколько было пиратов вместе с капитаном, если известны a и m. Так как капитан без команды просто пират, то n > 1.

Написал к ней код, но проблема в том, что контрольный пример проходит, а все остальное нет (примеры придумал сам).

Как я понял, логика там простая: есть N пиратов, есть a монет, которые забирает 1 пират, есть общее кол-во монет.

Для к.р. примера у меня вышла такая формула: `a + (a + 1) + (a + 2) * 2 = 25`.
Тогда `N = 3`.

Таким способом можно составить много своих примеров (типа `a = 6, m = 39`). Но они не проходят.

Объясните, в чем ошибка в коде.

Comment: а может свое решение покажешь, а то как-то трудно объяснить ошибку )

Comment: да, решить квадратное уравнение с ошибкой - это круто.

Comment: Совсем забыл! Вот мое решение: http://ideone.com/lroc1d

Comment: @Hamsternik то ли ideone.com хренова компилирует то ли у вас что-то не так: при максимальных значения должно быть 101, а не -1

Comment: @Hamsternik

- Для начала я бы рекомендовал вам разобраться, почему ваш код не работает для `a = 1, m = 5`.

- Далее, попробуйте решить задачу не подбором за `O(N),` а аналитически за `O(1)`. Сумма монет всегда равна `(a + 0) + (a + 1) + ... (a + n - 1) + (a + n - 1).` Выделите здесь арифметическую прогрессию, подсчитайте ее сумму по формуле, и решите полученное уравнение относительно `n`.

- Жалко, что для таких задач, скорее всего, технически нельзя поставить `Time Limit` так, чтобы решение за `O(N)` фейлилось по этому самому `Time Limit'у`.

Comment: @Котик: ну почему же нельзя? Если задать `N` очень большим (не влезающим в long long), линейный цикл (на ещё на кастомной арифметике) вылетит по времени запросто :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Олимпиадные задачи не решают в лоб. Надо чуть-чуть подумать.

```
a+(a+1)+...+(a+n-1)
```

это каждому следующему пирату больше на монетку. капитану еще `(a+n-1)`.

Очевидно это арифметическая прогрессия. Сумма которой равна:

```
 (2*a+n-1)*n/2
```

и капитану еще `a+n-1`.
В итоге имеем квадратное уравнение:

```
n*n/2+n*(a+1/2)+a-1=m
```

Дальше дискриминант и корни. Проверка на положительность корней, целочисленность корней.